# battery doesn't charge

Tags: 16.04, dell, laptop, battery

I have a laptop Dell inspiron 7559. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Then I wanted to make some battery thresholds for charging. I installed some package that should do this (I can't remember name of package). But my battery doesn't charge at all. 
But when I switch to second OS (Windows 10) battery charges fine. 
Could you please advice me something? Is there way to charge my battery up to 80%, for example? 
I have watched other posts about this theme, but them seems to be suitable only for ThinkPad owners.

Comment: better than exploding anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get remove tp-smapi-dkms
```

This is the module I think that you have installed.